# Mongoose array required in schema validation not working

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

In my schema I need to have a propery that is an array that must be always not null and not undefined.

So I defined it required, but the validation is not working as I expected, because if I omit the property no error is throw.

In case of simple property (not an array) this work as I expected

```
const nodeSchema = new Schema({
    address: { type: String, required: true },
    outputs: { type: [String], required: true }
})
```

Answer (score 7):

I think you can fix it adding a custom validator like this:

```
const nodeSchema = new Schema({
    address: { type: String, required: true },
    outputs: {
      type: [String],
      required: true,
      validate: [(value) => value.length > 0, 'No outputs'],
    }
})
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: I think using the default = undefined is a cleaner solution

Answer (score 1):

Just add the "**default**" as **undefined** and it will validate the array properly:

```
const nodeSchema = new Schema({
  address: { type: String, required: true },
  outputs: { type: [String], required: true, default: undefined },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

> Arrays implicitly have a default value of [] (empty array).

This was the problem

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure what is the fix? Can you share some code in your answer please?

Answer (score 0):

Array implicitly have a default value of [] (empty array).
if you add `default: undefined` it will fix the issue.